# TurtleBot Calibration -- continuous stream of warnings and errors

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the turtlebot calibration procedure for my turtlebot and I am getting a long list of scrolling errors and process restarts when I run the command:

roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch

I have run this before and it has worked, but now I am getting a long stream of the following.  I also have a weird error that when I run any ros packages the green power light on the create turns off... but it runs anyway (such as teleop or calibrate).  Namely the light turns off, the diagnostic pane says power system error, but the breaker is lit up green and the dashboard shows it to be in full mode and it responds to keyboard commands.  The error I get when running calibrate.launch is below:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/98264d65db7f94e9a12edbd61276af78

The robot is posting that stream to the terminal even as it is spinning and doing the calibration properly.  So it is running the program properly, but it is posting all of those errors and the power light has turned off.  Does anyone know what those errors mean?  I figure that might be the best place to start.

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11088/turtlebot-calibration----continuous-stream-of-warnings-and-errors/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have files a ticket to look into what is causing the errors: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/57

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-09-02**:
Thank you very much!  I really appreciate all of your help!